Keycloak upgrade from 18 to 25: Option: 'start-dev --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri'
I am trying to upgrade from Keycloak 18 to 25.0.2, but whenever I run docker-compose up, the keycloak container is stopping with this error:
Option: 'start-dev --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri' is not expected to contain whitespace, please remove any unnecessary quoting/escaping

So, to upgrade I just changed image to newer version, as per guide
KEYCLOAK_IMAGE=quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.2

This is how related docker-compose command look like. It works fine with 18.0.
command:
- "start-dev --spi-login-protocol-openid-connect-legacy-logout-redirect-uri=true --auto-build --hostname-strict=false -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.account_api=enabled --import-realm"

I already tried to change start-dev to kc.sh start-dev and kc.sh start, but it did not work out
